# try to bind selectedvalue from dropdownlist with selectParameters

Tags: asp.net

I'm try to solve this problem with `dropdownlist` and `selectedvalue` bind. If remove the `SelectedValue` from `dropdownlist` (`club_ddl` and `team_ddl`) works fine, but if add `SelectedValue` property to Bind `DataSource` return error "Databinding methods such as `Eval()`, `XPath()`, and `Bind()` can only be used in the context of a `databound` control" 
How can i solve this error? 
thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<html>

<head runat="server">
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">

<asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" id="result_db" DataFile="../App_Data/2016.mdb" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [result] WHERE [id] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [result] ([class], [club], [team], [skor]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [result]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [result] SET [class] = ?, [club] = ?, [team] = ?, [skor] = ? WHERE [id] = ?">
 <DeleteParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
 </DeleteParameters>
 <InsertParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="class" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="club" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="team" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="skor" Type="String" />
 </InsertParameters>
 <UpdateParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="class" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="club" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="team" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="skor" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
 </UpdateParameters>
 </asp:AccessDataSource>

 <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" id="class_db" DataFile="../App_Data/2016.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [class] FROM [team] GROUP BY [class] ORDER BY [class]"></asp:AccessDataSource>
  
 <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" id="club_db" DataFile="../App_Data/2016.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT [class], [club] FROM [result] WHERE ([class] = Α)">
  <selectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="result_fv$class_ddl" Name="class" Type="String" />
  </SelectParameters>
 </asp:AccessDataSource> 

 <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" id="team_db" DataFile="../App_Data/2016.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [team] WHERE (([class] = ?) AND ([club] = ?))">
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="result_fv$class_ddl" Name="class" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="result_fv$club_ddl" Name="club" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
 </SelectParameters>
 </asp:AccessDataSource>
 
<asp:FormView runat="server" id="result_fv" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="result_db" DefaultMode="Insert">
 
 <InsertItemTemplate>
  class:
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="class_ddl" DataSourceID="class_db" DataTextField="class" DataValueField="class" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("class") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  club:
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="club_ddl" DataSourceID="club_db" DataTextField="club" DataValueField="club" AutoPostBack="True" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("club") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  team:
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="team_ddl" DataSourceID="team_db" DataTextField="team" DataValueField="team" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("team") %>'></asp:DropDownList>
  <br />
  skor:
  <asp:TextBox id="skorTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("skor") %>' />
  <br />
  <asp:LinkButton id="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
  &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton id="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
 </InsertItemTemplate>
 
 </asp:FormView>

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you tried Eval in place of Bind?

Comment: yes I try Eval but did not work, the same error like Bind